# install java jre 5.0

Tags: java

Where to download java jre 5.0 to install on my windows7 64 ,I have java 6.0 installed on my machine but I need test my application under  jre 5.0.

Thanks

Comment: no need to download jre5.0 ,because The java  runtime is backwards compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the `Previous Releases` link on the [Java SE downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Here's the [direct link for J2SE 5.0 downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jdk5-jsp-142662.html) - look for the JRE download link and then select Windows x64 on the next page.